# How to place images on top of each other in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm currently working on a project to save the image parts and for one part I need to combine them together and have the effect of full sweater feel.Most things work except masking. I'm creating the API basically to have combined view as image

```py
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

I have 3 images: front piece, left and right arms:

```py
    background = Image.open('Front.png')
    foreground = Image.open('SleeveR.png')
    foreground1 = Image.open('SleeveL.png')
```

I have used `rembg` to remove the backgrounds which works fine.

I then get the `width` and `height` of arm piece and create a new mask to place it and put the front piece onto that arm piece:

```py
    width, height = foreground.size
    
    mask_im = Image.new("L", foreground.size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask_im)
    draw.rectangle((130, 70, width/2, height), fill=255)

    mask_im = mask_im.rotate(-20, resample=Image.NEAREST, expand=False)
    mask_im.save('mask_circle.jpg', quality=95)

    background.paste(foreground, (-120, 0), mask_im)
    background.save('result.png', quality=100)
```

I'm getting following result:

[image: Image output]

But, I want the output like this (made in Photoshop with same "cut" arm images):

[image: Image desired]

The problem appears with masking I assume, but couldn't figure out why transparent background gives that kind of result.

You can find images here:

Front: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofhYR.jpg

Left:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KXgU.jpg

Right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqJKj.jpg

Comment: you're using a rectangular mask that covers the entire overlay image. you should be using a mask derived from the image itself, which only overlaps the actual sleeve, not any background.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I solvedit myself by adding a new canvas and placing the images on top of each other. I don't know who wanted to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself by following way:

1. I created a new canvas using `Image.new()` function:

```py
    canvas = Image.new('RGBA', (700, 500), (0, 0, 0, 0))
```

2. Pasted the images on top of each other

```py
    canvas.paste(left_half, (int(ref1X)-185, int(ref1Y)-100), left_half)
    canvas.paste(right_half, (int(ref0X)-100, int(ref0Y)-100), right_half)

    canvas.paste(front, (0, 0), front)
    canvas.save('Image.png')
```

There was no need to apply any masking as I'm using a library `rembg` to remove the background of an image.